# What does USE_CTRLDLL=1 in SOURCES file do?

Tags: visual-c++, build, nmake, wdk

I am in the process of updating an older windows driver.  I am using Build.exe and the associated tool set included in the WinDDK (7600.16385.1).  Reviewing the SOURCES file I came across the following macro: `USE_CTRLDLL=1`.  I cannot find any documentation related to this on MSDN (**https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms910176.aspx**) or third party sites.  Any idea as to what this macro actually tells the tool set to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following answer was provided by Don Burn in the Windows Dev Center Forums ([What does  USE_CTRLDLL=1 in SOURCES file do?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/e856115e-1ead-4759-af5e-467a902944e2/what-does-usectrldll1-in-sources-file-do?forum=wdk#dfe3827c-d02f-4045-b376-6f070405568b)):

> I suspect someone typo'd meaning to put in USE_CRTDLL which is
>   obsolete and instead should be USE_MSVCRT.

Removing this MACRO has no apparent effect on the compilation, linking, or execution of the driver.  As Don implies, it is likely the result of a typo made during a maintenance update.